# ArrayList not adding more than 1 value

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, unity-game-engine

I've made a prefab that contains an inputfield and a corresponding text field.

Whenever I click "add", another prefab will be loaded - and it works great! However, I'm encountering a problem with my ArrayList. For some reason, it doesn't want to add any other values except for the first.

Here's a snippet of my code.

This method is attached to the prefab and it adds whatever text (i.e. input) we have to the ArrayList 'CardsQuestList'.

```
public void returnQuestion ( Text questionInp) {

    print ("I just changed: " + questionInp.text);

    cardsQuestList.Add (questionInp.text);
 }
```

I have declared my ArrayList as a field. I did not put it in Start(), as it didn't really work out.

Here's how I defined the ArrayList :

```
    ArrayList cardsQuestList = new ArrayList ();
```

Here's how I print the ArrayList:

```
 foreach (string s in cardsQuestList) {
        print ("CardsQuestList : " + s);
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong? It only saves the very first input (i.e. questionInp). Only once .. and even though more are added, it still insists on keeping only the first one.

Comment: What event is your returnQuestion attached to/triggered by and where in your code is the cardsQuestList defined? It sounds as if it's not being triggered on subsequent calls or your cardsQuestList is being cleared and reset every time it's called.

Comment: returnQuestion() is triggered by my input field's "On End Edit".
It can print out the text fine, no matter which clone is doing it.

I've defined the cardsQuestList ArrayList in the beginning of my script ... Where the fields are (asuming it's also called 'fields' in C#).  So it's not in a method or anything .. I tried putting it in the void Start() method, but that didn't work either, @JonathonOgden

Comment: I don't think the cardsQuestLit is being cleared. It still insists on keeping the very first value, so I believe something else is wrong. I'm not sure what, though.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Can you post the whole code? That would be helpful in this case. Also, I recommend you use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. It's better for performance reasons.

Comment: @Progammer, sadly I cannot post any more. I'm doing an internship so I'm bound by a contract not to share the code. 

I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to concatenate all the text in your list and print it in 1 long string or print each text element individually?

Comment: @JonathonOgden, I'm trying to print each text element individually.

Comment: Appreciate you're under a contract, but can you share more code by masking or generalizing parts that would breach the contract? Difficult to assist further without it.